# How to download a PDF file from Sitecore Form(9.2) custom submit action

Tags: sitecore-forms, pdf

I have a pdf file of the type byte array. Using Sitecore form `custom submit action`, I need to download/open the same as pdf in the user's machine. I tried to achieve the same by adding response headers for content disposition but was not successful.

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

[image]

I am getting a error in `~\wwwroot\s92.dev.local\Views\FormBuilder\Form.cshtml` as

[image]

Also in browser I see something like this..
[image]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do it in the next way:

```
 ID id = new ID(mediaId);
 
 if (id.IsNull)
    return;
 
 MediaItem mediaItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items.GetItem(id);
 
 if (mediaItem != null)
            {
                Stream stream = mediaItem.GetMediaStream();
                long fileSize = stream.Length;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)fileSize];
                stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                stream.Close();
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = String.Format(mediaItem.MimeType);
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + mediaItem.Name + "." + mediaItem.Extension);
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                Response.End();
            }
```

mediaId represent the id of your media item. The code is almost the same with your code. I notice some small differences like: a space before filename when you add header, cache for response and how the stream of pdf is read.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your response. I am actually trying to load a file from servie API but not from medialibrary. Hence made changes accordingly but still I see the page as given in the post above.